# gettattr , "attributes must be string" error in python

Tags: python, typeerror, getattr

I am trying to use `getattr` function in my code using generator

```
li=[]
m=[method for method in dir(li) if callable(getattr(li,method))]
print getattr(li,(str(i) for i in m))
```

**Error**:

```
TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string
```

if I am using string coercion on i, then why this error shows up?

Also,if I use the code

```
li=[]
m=[method for method in dir(li) if callable(getattr(li,method))]
for i in range(10):
    print getattr(li,str(m[i]))
```

Then there is no error

I am new to python, forgive me if i am making very elementary mistake, please can someone elaborate on the error. Thanks

**Edit**: The same principle works for this code (it is an example from Dive into python). Here,the same thing is done then why there is no error?

```
def info(object, spacing=10, collapse=1):
    """Print methods and doc strings.

    Takes module, class, list, dictionary, or string."""
    methodList = [e for e in dir(object) if callable(getattr(object, e))]
    processFunc = collapse and (lambda s: " ".join(s.split())) or (lambda s: s)
    print "\n".join(["%s %s" %
                     (method.ljust(spacing),
                      processFunc(str(getattr(object, method).__doc__)))
                     for method in methodList])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, given your edit I have changed my answer. You appear to be expecting generators to do something different to what they do.

You don't pass a generator to a function and have the function work on each item produced by the generator, you loop over a generator and then perform the functions you want inside the loop.

However, here you don't need a generator expression - just loop over your list - E.g:

```
for method in m:
    print(getattr(li, method))
```

If you did want to use a generator expression, then you could use it here instead of constructing the list in the first place:

```
for method in (method for method in dir(li) if callable(getattr(li, method))):
    print(getattr(li, method))
```

Although note that, for what you are trying to do here, [the `inspect` module](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) can help avoid a lot of what you are doing.

Comment: but, what bout string coercion, is it of no importance?

Comment: It's not string coercion in Python, you are simply constructing a new string from the value you pass into `str()`. That said, it doesn't matter because it's inside the generator expression, so it's not what you are passing to the function.

Comment: OK, you mean to say that instead of passing generators i shall pass my  arguments first?

Comment: I don't really see why you are using a generator there in the first place, what are you trying to do?

Comment: i am just practicing for passing generators as arguments

Comment: @sum2000 Because `str.join()` takes an iterable as it's argument.

Comment: But, the argument inside getattr is called again using generators, which you told what generators cant do?

Comment: @sum2000 You need to look at the documentation for the functions you are using. Some of them take iterables as arguments, but most don't. A generator can't magically make a function take an iterable where it doesn't make sense to do so. `str.join()` takes an iterable as it needs multiple parts to join, `getattr()` takes *one* attribute to fetch and return.

Comment: thanks, did not know about iterables, can you point to some good link for understanding the concept? apart from python documentation?

Comment: i understood what u said, that join can take iterables as arguments, but inside join there is a getattr used,is that getattr taking iterable as argument? because it's second argument is `method`

Comment: @sum2000 `getattr()` is being called inside the generator. You may want to read up on how generator expressions work.